# IntelliJ 14 Scala Editor showing errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've just uninstalled IntelliJ 13 and installed 14 (community edition). I set up jdk, and then installed the Scala plugin, and created a new Scala > SBT project. It asked me to setup the Scala SDK which I did. I let it autoimport, and it created the src. etc folders. I then created a scala class. It compiles and runs fine. However, IntelliJ shows built in scala stuff as errors. For example:

[image: List and println show errors]

For some reason, intellij is showing all scala library stuff as errors. However, the program compiles and runs fine. Has anybody else come across this?

Comment: Yes, I faced the same issue here. But it is just concerning some corner cases (implicit conversions, etc.). My project is a sbt project by the way. I tried to change the `Scala` settings in `Preferences` but still no success. Should be a bug in new IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I had similar errors, and solved them with the "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart..." command (choosing "Invalidate and Restart" when prompted). Intellij restarts, and then takes some time to rebuild a cache that was apparently corrupted in my case. It might be worth trying.

Comment: Just read this after having just completely obliterated scala, ivy, maven, sbt, ideaIC14 folders, restarting and reinstalling everything. Works !! Looking back, invalidating caches may have been easier. Thanks.

Comment: @Cyäegha clear cache works like a charm ! Thank you

Comment: @Cyäegha You should convert your comment to an answer!